# How to make sure Rails points to updated model name when running a migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-migrations

I’m running into an issue where one of my migration is failing. This is how the existing migration looks like.

```
class AddColumnToTwitterPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    add_column :twitter_posts, :status, :string, default: "new"
    add_index :twitter_posts, :status

    add_default_status_to_existing_posts
  end

  def down
    remove_column :twitter_posts, :status
  end

  private

    def add_default_status_to_existing_posts
      TwitterPost.find_each do |post|
        post.update!(status: "new")
      end
    end
end
```

Now I have moved model `TwitterPost` to namespace `Twitter::Post`.

So whenever this migration runs it fails to find this model. How can I make sure that rails picks up on the updated namespace instead of the old model name specified in the migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should not put any "data migrations" inside of your "schema migrations". This is considered bad practice, exactly for the reason which causes a problem for you now. One way to solve your problem is to use Rake tasks, as suggested by [Thoughtbot](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/data-migrations-in-rails). If you need to update data after a specific migration, you create a rake task doing the updates you need.

This way, your database schema migrations will always work since they don't depend on the presence of any specific model defined in your app.

A rake task might in your case look like:

```
namespace :twitter_posts do
  desc "Update twitter posts"
  task update_status_new: :environment do
    puts "Going to update #{TwitterPost.count} twitter_posts"

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      TwitterPost.update_all(status: "new")
    end

    puts " All done now!"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, Dave. I'll look into setting up rake task. But this still doesn't solve the problem of failing migration since it's already been committed and I cannot edit it either.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no other way then to rollback your commit (and create a rake task), or update the migration (override TwitterPost by Twitter::Post), or, worst case scenario, temporarily move the class Twitter::Post back to TwitterPost.